# $A,B$ be Hermitian.Is this true that $tr[(AB)^2]\le tr(A^2B^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace

Suppose $A,B \in {M_n}$ be Hermitian.Is this true that $tr[(AB)^2]\le tr(A^2B^2)$?

Answer (score 20):

Yes.  Equality holds iff $AB = BA$.

**Hint:** Note that $AB - BA$ is skew-Hermitian, and that
$$
2\operatorname{trace}[(AB)^2] - 2\operatorname{trace}(A^2B^2) =\\
\operatorname{trace}(ABAB + BABA -ABBA - BAAB)=\\
\operatorname{trace}[(AB - BA)^2]
$$

**Note:** The inequality assumes that both $\operatorname{trace}[(AB)^2]$ and $\operatorname{trace}(A^2B^2)$ are real.  This is fine because the product of Hermitian matrices necessarily has a real trace.  Note that
$$
\operatorname{trace}[(A+aI)(B+bI)] =\\
\operatorname{trace}(AB) + 
b\operatorname{trace}(A) + 
a \operatorname{trace}(B) +
abn
$$
and that $a,b>0$ may be chosen so that $A +aI$ and $B+bI$ are positive definite.  The product of (Hermitian) positive definite matrices always has positive eigenvalues.

Comment: The end note is wonderful. +1

Comment: @user1551 it feels like there should be a simpler justification, but I'll settle for the quick and dirty explanation.

Comment: ‘The product of positive matrices always has positive eigenvalues’ that’s interesting, can you show/hint briefly why that is true?

Comment: @icv one quick-and-dirty proof: Suppose that $A,B$ are positive.  $A$ has positive definite square root $A^{1/2}$.  It follows that
$$
A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2} = A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}
$$
Since $B$ is positive definite, $MBM^*$ is positive definite for any invertible $M$, such as $M = A^{1/2}$.  So, we see from the above that $AB$ is similar to a positive definite matrix.  So, $AB$ has positive eigenvalues.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2884109/81360) gives a quicker proof that $AB$ has real trace.