# Is the following equation true about trace of a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Is this true?
$\operatorname{tr}(AB)^k = \operatorname{tr}(A^k B^k)$

If so, how can one provide proof or counter example?

I tried it with the following two matrices and it turned out to be true:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
but would it apply to all matrices? and how can one provide proof?

Comment: Try some matrices that are less special than the two that you posted before you edited the question.

Comment: confirmed it with a more normal matrix, and the equation still holds true.

Comment: If by $tr(AB)^k$ you mean $(tr(AB))^k$, this isn't even true with $B=I$.  Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$ and $k=2$.  $(tr(AB))^k = 6^2=36$ whereas $tr(A^kB^k)=18$

Comment: If you just generated 2 random matrices (e.g. with entries i.i.d. standard normal; in matlab, randn(n) for n x n), you'd probably find a counterexample on the first try.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303910/a-b-be-hermitian-is-this-true-that-trab2-le-tra2b2/1303916#1303916) for a class of counterexamples